# Skipped nodes when trying to sort linked list

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, bubble-sort

I'm trying to sort a linked list.

The code doesn't work properly, it skips some nodes on checking how to minimize the issues while sorting the nodes.

```
void sortNodes(){
    node *parrser = head, *current = NULL;
    node*temp;
    while (parrser->next!= NULL){
        current = head;
        while (current->next!= NULL){
            // cout << current->no << "next" << current->next->no;
            if (current->no > current->next->no){
                temp = current->next;
                current->next = temp->next;
                temp->next = current;
            }
            else
                current = current->next;
        }
        parrser = parrser->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tag the question with appropriate language tags and explain, what is exactly wrong: in what cases the nodes are skipped, how you're checking that, etc.

Comment: linked lists are best sorted using [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Answer (score 0):

The code compares current->no with current->next->no. If out of order, the code should swap current with current->next, but this requires updating whatever points to current, which the code is currently not doing.

The bubble sort in this case moves the node with the relatively largest number to the end of the list on each inner loop. The outer loop needs to start at the beginning of the list each time, so that the node with the smallest number ends up at the front of the list. Use a swap flag that is set if any swaps are done, and if it ends up not set after a pass, the sort is done.

Instead of bubble sort, it would be simpler to create a new empty sorted list, and then remove nodes from the original list and insert them in order into the initially empty sorted list.